# Grails 1.3.7 clean project cannot serve utf8 files

Tags: tomcat, grails, utf-8, internationalization

I create a clean grails application and run `grails dev war` and deploy under Tomcat 6.0.32. When I attempt to download [this file](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/utf8/) via `localhost:8080/utf8.html`, I get a response with busted encoding and characters.

When I create a `ROOT/` directory in `web-app/` and serve the same file, the response is fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: what happens when you open the file utf8.html directly in your browser (not through localhost)? maybe the file is saved with an incorrect encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a controller to serve files properly. With no other solutions, this is all you have.